# passing a value to php from textbox using jquery doesnt work please help

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5b1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  

<input type="text" id="textbox">
<button id="inlinesubmit_button" type="button">submit</submit>


<script>

function call_this()
{
alert(<?php echo $_POST['text'];?>);
}


$('#inlinesubmit_button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sync_loading1.php",
       data: {text:$('#textbox').val()}
    });

call_this();
});

</script>
```

this gives undefined in alert box please help me in pointing out what am I doing wrong

Comment: PHP runs on the server. JavaScript runs in the browser.

Comment: Can you please describe, step by step, what the expected program flow should be?

1).  User types text.
2).  User Submits text.
3).  Server does something with it.

The first two are pretty obvious... not sure what is in step 3 or what the subsequent steps are.

Comment: yes u are correct the server takes that text queries mysql database .... and returns name appended with id and I further need to use this in javascript ..... hope you get an Idea

Comment: yeah, I added a solution below.  Hope it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to wrap it in quotes (`'` or `"`), to make it a string.

```
alert('<?php echo $_POST['text'];?>');
```

It also appears you are overlooking something with how JavaScript runs (client side) and PHP (server side). They can't directly communicate; PHP can echo JavaScript, and JavaScript can make HTTP requests to PHP files.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to figure out what you're doing... but the key is that you need the client code, plus the server handler.

Your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5b1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function call_this(data, status, xhr)
{
   alert(data);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#inlinesubmit_button').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
          url: "sync_loading1.php",
         data: {text:$('#textbox').val()},
      success: call_this
      });
   });
 });
</script>

<input type="text" id="textbox">
<button id="inlinesubmit_button" type="button">submit</submit>
```

sync_loading1.php

```
<?php
// Perform action.  Maybe you want to log this into a DB.
//   Maybe you want to just print out some text:
echo nl2br('Hello world.  Here was my input:'.$_POST['text']);
```

Comment: Just edited.  I left in your original call_this() call, which would have failed since it was operating on the click, not on the async return from the Ajax.

Comment: Hi John Thank you very much for your effort ... but this is not what I trying to do .... Let me explain you sorry for the confusion ..... the main thing that I am trying here to achieve is

Comment: Hi John Thank you very much for your effort ... but this is not what I trying to do, Let me explain you sorry for the confusion, the main thing that I am trying here to achieve is..
1) User types in textbox 
2) I pass its value to PHP
3) php does some processing and then the output acts as a parameter for the Javascript..Does that makes sense..i.e after the value is posted to PHP, I am calling a javascript function(say fun();)..PHP has a variable say test .. now what I want is inside fun I want the value of variable test to do something like this..var JS_test=<?php echo $_POST['test']; ?>

Comment: The PHP in sync_loading has to echo something back if you want to use it.  In my example, I'm just writing out a string.  You can also do JSON or whatever else if you want.  For json, for instance, you may do something like json_encode(array('id'=>32, 'text'=>12));  From there, the call_this function is the callback and will take the stuff from PHP as a parameter.

Comment: I will try that and let you know

Answer (score 1):

This function isnt going to work sadly, you are running an ajax call to an external file, and the external file cant do an alert because its not being viewed by the user. if you want to alert the data of the text field, just do `alert($('#textbox').val());`