# PHP getting value immediately after clicking on checkbox

Tags: php, html, forms

How to get value from checkbox or radio button immediately after clicking on it and write it in textfield without using reset or submit button?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="age" value="21-29">21-29 <input type="text" name="yourAge" value="">
```

Comment: You'll want a javascript event to do that, not php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass value from html form to php without submitting the form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065101/pass-value-from-html-form-to-php-without-submitting-the-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shehary is on point but there is always room for more.

> JS

```
<script>       
 var changeInput = function  (val){
            var input = document.getElementById("age");
            input.value = val;
        }
</script>
```

> HTML

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="age" value="21-29" onclick='changeInput(this.value);' >21-29
    <input type="text" name="yourAge" value="" id="age">
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNNoBE)

Comment: Thanks, but you are using JS. I need the code only in PHP. My teacher told me to do it just with PHP.

Comment: @StykPohlavsson Err, no. you'll need to use either JS/jQuery or an AJAX call to POST request back to the PHP on the server. It can't be done in PHP only since PHP is a server-side scripting language.

Comment: @StykPohlavsson either your teacher needs to go back to school to learn the difference between server-side and client-side language or you miss understood what your teacher told you. `get value from  checkbox or radio button immediately after clicking on it` there is no possible way without jQuery, Ajax or java-script because then you were asking `without using reset or submit button`

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this with jQuery click function [More Detail Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="age" value="21-29" id="age">21-29
<input type="text" name="yourAge" value="" id="yourAge">
```

JQuery

```
$("#age").click(function () {
    $("#yourAge").val($("#age").val());

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtvdv3ru/)

Comment: Thanks for and idea but I would like to see it in PHP.

Comment: what you mean see it in PHP? can you explain more?

Comment: I mean to write it in a PHP without using JavaScript or JQuery. I would like to see the code you wrote but written in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, and my code may not be great, but I like to use this.

```
<?php
    $get= "?checked";
    $checked= "";
    if(isset($_GET['checked'])){
        $get= "";
        $checked= "checked";
    } 
?>
<a href="waiting_in_db.php<?=$get?>">
    <input type="checkbox" <?=$checked?> >
</a>
```

But I prefer using CSS and links without the checkbox.