# how can we pass input type value in to an variable with out submit or click

Tags: php, variables

i know the question doesn't looks good but am not getting any idea because am new to here.my question is can we store the value of an input type in to an variable.here in this case

```
<input type="text" name="statustochange">
```

having an value now i want to store that value in to an variable with out submit or click

i got the value in to

`name="statustochange"`

from this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.modal').modal({
    ready: function(modal, trigger) {
      modal.find('input[name="statustochange"]').val(trigger.data('status'))
     }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Use `Javascript/Jquery` And `AJAX`

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065101/pass-value-from-html-form-to-php-without-submitting-the-form

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="statustochange" value="<?php echo $str; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Into a js variable? Use a `onChange` event!

Into a php variable? Use a js `onChange` event to trigger a [postback in Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782230/ajax-passing-data-to-php-script) (invisible to the user)

Edit: More realavent link