# is there a way to automatically submit a form when the user inputs the correct answer?

Tags: php, ajax, forms

In my website I am working on making a page that will display an image, and has a form with a text input field. I want to know if there is a way to automatically submit said form when the user types in the correct answer in the text input field?

Comment: You can definitely do that with JavaScript without effort. Your form will have a `submit()` method.

Comment: _I want to know if there is a way[...]_ Yes, there is. But this is definitely unrelated to mysql, java, and in most cases php (as the submit itself is done on the client side)

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065101/pass-value-from-html-form-to-php-without-submitting-the-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using JavaScript and PHP [json_encode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var inputField = document.getElementById("yourInputField");
    inputField.addEventListener("input", submitFormIfCorrect);
});


function submitFormIfCorrect(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    var correctAnswer = <?php echo json_encode($answer) ?>;

    if (element.value === correctAnswer) {
        // submit form
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have been more clear, my website is programmed in php. The answer that the user needs to imput is pulled from a mysql query and then turned into a php variable.. is there a way to automatically submit the form when that php variable is typed into the text input box?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, it is working, but it's not auto submitting I have to click out of the input field to submit.

Comment: My bad. I updated my answer. It should behave like you want with `inputField.addEventListener("input", submitFormIfCorrect);`.

Comment: Works absolutely flawless, thank you so much. I could not wrap my brain around how to make this function!

Comment: No problem. :) Please accept my answer to indicate the question is solved.

Comment: Absolutely, there are a lot of critics and people who would rather nitpick than help, but you have been nothing but superb in helping. Thanks again.